# Creating a Library for an Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I have some code that I wanted to put into a library which uses another library, [SoftwareSerial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial). Now I added the SoftwareSerial.h and SoftwareSerial.cpp files to the same folder as the library I'm creating.

My header file looks something like this:

```cpp
#ifndef MyLibrary_h
#define MyLibrary_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

#define MyLibrary_VERSION       1       // software version of this library


//DEFINE ALL CLASS VARIABLES

#define DATA_BUFFER_SIZE 50  //soft serial has 63 byte buffer.

class MyLibrary
{
    public:
        MyLibrary(uint8_t port_in, uint8_t port_out);
        float getSomeValue(uint8_t some_index);
    private:
        SoftwareSerial _serial;
                //Not sure if I should add the constructors below to the above declaration.
                //(uint8_t in_pin=4, uint8_t out_pin=5, bool logic_reversed = false);
        float convertSomeValue(byte upperbyte, byte lowerbyte);
        void flushSerialBuffer();
}; 

#endif
```

My .cpp file looks like this:

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "MyLibrary.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"


MyLibrary::MyLibrary(uint8_t in_pin, uint8_t out_pin)
{

    bool logic_reversed = false;
    this->_serial(in_pin*, out_pin*, logic_reversed);
        //I tried the declaration below as well.
    //SoftwareSerial _serial(in_pin*, out_pin*, logic_reversed);
}

float MyLibrary::getSomeValue(uint8_t sensor_index) {
    float someValue = 1.1;
    return someValue;
}

float MyLibrary::convertSome(byte upperbyte, byte lowerbyte) {
    float someValue = 0.9;
    return someValue;
}

void MyLibrary::flushSerialBuffer() {
    //Flush serial buffer
    while(_serial.available())
        char c = _serial.read();
}
```

I would like [SoftwareSerial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) to be a private field in MyLibrary (preferably static but not necessary) but I've tried many was of declaring it but nothing seems to work. I keep getting errors like `no matching function for call to 'SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial()` or `invalid use of qualified-name 'MyLibrary::_serial'`.

I got it to compile fine once by declaring `static SoftwareSerial _serial;` in my .h file, and `SoftwareSerial MyLibrary::_serial(4,5,false);` at the top of my .cpp file. The thing is, I would like to set the ports of `_serial` in my constructor for MyLibrary (so I can create a MyLibrary that uses specific in/out pins for SoftwareSerial) and not have them explicitly declared at the top of the .cpp file.

I'm not so familiar with C coding and Arduino so it would be a great help if someone could explain to me how to declare these properly in the .h file and instanciate them with the correct ports in the MyLibrary constructor or a MyLibrary.begin() function (or something of the like).

Thanks in advance for you **helpful** comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is to make your constructor do the initialization as follows:

```
class MyLibrary{
public:
   MyLibrary(uint8_t, uint8_t);
   //...
private:
   SoftwareSerial _serial;
   //...
};

MyLibrary::MyLibrary(uint8_t in, uint8_t out)
   : _serial(in, out)
{
   //do initialization
}
```

This syntax might seem strange at first, but although it isn't quite as pretty, it clearly differentiates *initialization* of variables vs *operations* on variables, which is something that placing the initialization in the body of the constructor can make slightly fuzzy.  As a rule, UNLESS you use this syntax to initialize a member variable, C++ will call the default constructor, which will cause a compile error iff the member does not have a callable default constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for and this worked fine for initializing a SofwareSerial in the constructor of MyLibrary. Just for completeness here, how would I initialize it if I had declared it as `static SoftwareSerial _serial;` in my header file? Is that even good practice with static variables? Initializing them in the constructor doesn't seem quite right to me.

Comment: I assume you mean as a static member variable?  In which case, you pick a .cpp file you want the object to "live" in and use `SoftwareSerial DataLogger::_serial(a, b);`.

Comment: Sorry `MyLibrary::_serial(a, b)`.  Though MyLibrary sounds more like the name of a namespace than a class...