# Using SoftwareSerial as a private member variable

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to convert Sparkfun's example code for the SM130 RFID Reader into a class/library that's encapsulated nicely and can be used in multiple arduino sketches.

Sparkfun Example Code: https://github.com/sparkfun/RFID_Evaluation_Shield/blob/master/Firmware/RFID_Eval_13_56MHz.ino

Most of it went pretty smoothly, until I tried to make the Software Serial communications a member variable -- I keep getting errors like:

```
/Users/scottnla/Dropbox/arduino/libraries/SM130/SM130.cpp: In constructor 'SM130::SM130()':
/Users/scottnla/Dropbox/arduino/libraries/SM130/SM130.cpp:8: error: no matching function for call to 'SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial()'
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.h:83: note: candidates are: SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(uint8_t, uint8_t, bool)
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.h:48: note:                 SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(const SoftwareSerial&)
```

I found a stackoverflow post that seems to address this issue ([Creating a Library for an Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169714/creating-a-library-for-an-arduino)), but their solution doesn't seem to work for me.  The IDE's error messages seem to indicate that I can only use a 'base initializer' in a constructor; but this isn't what I want.  What's the best way to deal with the problem that I'm having in my code?

Thanks!

Code below:

SM130.h

```
#ifndef SM130_h
#define SM130_h

#include<Arduino.h>
#include <WConstants.h>

class SM130 {
  public:
    SM130();
    void connect(int RX, int TX);
    void check_for_notag();
    void halt_tag();
    void parse_tag();
    void print_serial();
    void seek_tag();
    void set_flag();

  private:
    int rfid_flag;
    int data[11];
    SoftwareSerial rfid;
};

#endif
```

SM130.cpp

```
#include <WProgram.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "SM130.h"

SM130::SM130() {
  rfid_flag = 0;
}

void SM130::connect(int RX, int TX) : rfid(RX, TX) {
 if(!Serial.available()) {
    Serial.begin(9600);
  }
  Serial.println("Connecting to SM130 RFID Reader...");
  //rfid = SoftwareSerial(RX, TX);
  rfid.begin(19200);
  if(rfid.available()) {
    rfid.println("Connected to SM130 RFID Reader!");
  }
  delay(10);
}

void SM130::check_for_notag() {
  seek_tag();
  delay(10);
  parse_tag();
  set_flag();

  if(rfid_flag == 1) {
    seek_tag();
    delay(10);
    parse_tag();
  }
}

void SM130::halt_tag() {
  rfid.write(0xFF);
  rfid.write((byte)0x00);   //manual typecasting needed for 0x00 to differentiate it from null pointer -- silly c compilers!
  rfid.write(0x01);
  rfid.write(0x93);
  rfid.write(0x94);
}

void SM130::parse_tag() {
 while(rfid.available()) {
   if(rfid.read() == 0xFF) {
     for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
       data[i] = rfid.read();
     }
   }
 }
}

void SM130::print_serial() {
  if(rfid_flag == 1) {
      Serial.print(data[5],HEX);
      Serial.print(data[6],HEX);
      Serial.print(data[7],HEX);
      Serial.print(data[8],HEX);
      Serial.println();
  }
}

void SM130::seek_tag() {
  //insert hex tags here
  rfid.write(0xFF);
  rfid.write((byte)0x00); //manual typecasting needed for 0x00 to differentiate it from null pointer -- silly c compilers!
  rfid.write(0x01);
  rfid.write(0x82);
  rfid.write(0x83);
}

void SM130::set_flag() {
  if(data[2] == 6) {
    rfid_flag++;
  }
  if(data[2] == 2) {
    rfid_flag = 0;
  }
}
```

My arduino sketch:

```
#include <SM130.h>

void read_serial();
SM130 rfidReader;

void setup() {
  //Connect to computer
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //connect to SM130
  rfidReader.connect(7,8);
}

void loop() {
  read_serial();
}

void read_serial() {
  rfidReader.seek_tag();
  delay(10);
  rfidReader.parse_tag();
  rfidReader.set_flag();
  rfidReader.print_serial();
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: Good question! Forgot to remove the tag.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /Users/scottnla/Dropbox/arduino/libraries/SM130/SM130.cpp: In
>   constructor 'SM130::SM130()':
>   /Users/scottnla/Dropbox/arduino/libraries/SM130/SM130.cpp:8: error: no
>   matching function for call to 'SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial()'

This part tells you everything. SoftwareSerial has no constructor without argument list, so you try to call a non-existing function. 
If you don't specify a class member in constructor's initialization list, compiler by default calls () constructor for it. It is equivalent of:

```
SoftwareSerial ss;
```

if we weren't talking about classes.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html

Unfortunately SoftwareSerial has no Set methods.

http://arduino.cc/de/Reference/SoftwareSerial

But worry not, dynamic memory allocation comes to the rescue! For example:

SM130.h

```
#ifndef SM130_h
#define SM130_h

#include<Arduino.h>
#include <WConstants.h>

class SM130 {
  public:
    SM130();
    ~SM130();
    void connect(int RX, int TX);
    void check_for_notag();
    void halt_tag();
    void parse_tag();
    void print_serial();
    void seek_tag();
    void set_flag();

  private:
    int rfid_flag;
    int data[11];
    SoftwareSerial* rfid;
};

#endif
```

SM130.cpp (only some methods)

```
SM130::SM130() : rfid(NULL)  {
  rfid_flag = 0;
}

void SM130::connect(int RX, int TX) {

    if(!Serial.available()) 
    {
        Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    Serial.println("Connecting to SM130 RFID Reader...");
    if (NULL != rfid)
    {
        delete rfid;
    }
    rfid = new SoftwareSerial(RX, TX)
    rfid->begin(19200);
    if(rfid->available())
    {
       rfid->println("Connected to SM130 RFID Reader!");
    }
    delay(10);
 }


 ~SM130::SM130() 
 {
     if (NULL != rfid)
     {
         delete rfid;
     }
 }
```

I only posted my versions of constructor, connect and destructor (good to have it for avoiding memory leaks).

Don't forget about:

1. Checking if rfid is not NULL (better use `NULL != rfid` instead of `rfid != NULL`, because compiler will tell you about mistakes like `if (rfid = NULL)`)
2. Changing `rfid.` to `rfid->`

You can even add `disconnect` method, which deletes old rfid and sets pointer to NULL:

```
     void SM130::disconnect() {
         delete rfid;
         rfid = NULL;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks!  This all makes sense except, I get the following error:

/Users/scottnla/Dropbox/arduino/libraries/SM130/SM130.h:34: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'SoftwareSerial' with no type
/Users/scottnla/Dropbox/arduino/libraries/SM130/SM130.h:34: error: expected ';' before '*' token

where line 34 is the line 'SoftwareSerial* rfid;'.  I tried applying google to this issue, but can't find a consistent answer that explains what the problem is for me.  Hrmm.

Comment: add `#include <SoftwareSerial.h>` in SM130.h file. Your compiler does not know what "SoftwareSerial" class is. Also: declare it as a pointer, namely add an asterisk after class name. Take a look at my version of your class, it's there.

Comment: I can't edit my comment for some reason, but both of those are already in my file.

EDIT: I was able to fix it by placing the #include in my sketch file (not the library file) -- why does that make a difference?

Comment: Are you sure it was in header file before? Because in both sketch and .cpp file SerialSoftware.h is above inclusion your class, so from compiler's point of view it's as good as having it in the header. Maybe it was because in error message you quoted it still wasn't a pointer? Hard to say. Good thing you got this sorted out.